# Vim command for "edit a copy of this file"

Tags: vim, ex

A pattern I seem to be following right now is:

- edit a file until I like it
- `:w another-file` to use it as a starting point for `another-file`
- `:e another-file` to polish up `another-file`

Is there an existing ex command to do the latter two steps at once? Something like `:writeAndEdit another-file`?

I can fake one using vimscript, I just want to know if there's an existing command.

Comment: Good question. I use that method too, and it's very error prone.

Comment: Vim questions belong here.  This was voted on in meta long ago.

Comment: What I used to do was :w newfile and then :[UPARROW][HOME][DEL]e[ENTER] which takes the last command and changes it from a :w to an :e so that your chance of a typo is much less. Still two steps just less error prone. Now that I know about saveas I will be using that but I thought I would mention it here because the idea could be useful for other tasks.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Could `:saveas` do the job?

```
:sav[eas][!] [++opt] {file}
            Save the current buffer under the name {file} and set
            the filename of the current buffer to {file}.  The
            previous name is used for the alternate file name.
```

Answer (score 11):

You are less likely to overwrite your original file if you open the new file first and then copy the original file into the buffer.

```
:e another-file
:r original-file
```

I found an answer for you. Type `:help saveas` and enjoy!

> :sav[eas][!] [++opt] {file}           Save
>   the current buffer under the name
>   {file} and set            the filename of the
>   current buffer to {file}.  The
>             previous name is used for the
>   alternate file name.          The [!] is
>   needed to overwrite an existing file.
>             When 'filetype' is empty filetype
>   detection is done             with the new
>   name, before the file is written.
>             When the write was successful
>   'readonly' is reset.          {not in Vi}

Comment: @rampion not according to the timestamps, it looks like Judge was 1s quicker!